# Angular 4 ngValue everything but given values

Tags: angular

Angular 4 lets users display items by value easily, but how to display a value if value exists but is none of the selected?

For example, if we have this select box:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="yearChoice">
  <option [ngValue]="'one_year'">1 year</option>
  <option [ngValue]="'two_years'">2 years</option>
  <option [ngValue]="'three_years'">3 years</option>
  <option [ngValue]="'four_years'">4 years</option>
  <option [ngValue]="'other'">other</option>
</select>
```

And also this input field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="6 months" *ngIf="!['one_year', 'two_years', 'three_years', 'four_years'].includes(yearChoice)" [(ngModel)]="yearChoice">
```

So if 'other' is selected, the input field is shown. Now, if user changes the input field, the select option would get corrupted, since the value is no longer 'other'.

My question is: is there a way to make this input field changeable while still selecting 'other' option from select menu after navigating/saving etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its happen to you is that both select and input are on the same ngmodel.
Change ng model inside input to yearChoiceInput.

Its may look like this :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="6 months" *ngIf="yearChoice === 'other'" [(ngModel)]="yearChoiceInput"
```

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to use a solution similar to this. I thought maybe there's another possibility, but now I'm going to use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ngModelChange` callback to run your logic and decide to show the input field or not.

```
<select [ngModel]="yearChoice" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option [ngValue]="'one_year'">1 year</option>
  <option [ngValue]="'two_years'">2 years</option>
  <option [ngValue]="'three_years'">3 years</option>
  <option [ngValue]="'four_years'">4 years</option>
  <option [ngValue]="'other'">other</option>
</select>
```

for input field:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="6 months" *ngIf="showInput" [(ngModel)]="yearChoice">
```

in Controller:

```
onChange(e) {
  //decide to show or not show input field
  this.showInput = true/false // true or false based on selected value
}
```

Comment: This would still leave the select option displaying issue.

Comment: using such a heavy condition in ngIf is really bad for performance. You should move the logic to controller. You should do this evaluation only when select value changes. The template expression will be evaluated every time dirty check happens

Answer (score -1):

I am not clear what you want to achieve but see if this helps:

**If you want to use reactive form** then,below is the solution: 
In ts, 
 create an array of items.
Example:

```
 items= [ {
    key: 'A+', value: 'A+'
  }, {
    key: 'A−', value: 'A−'
  }, {
    key: 'B+', value: 'B+'
  }, {
    key: 'B−', value: 'B−'
  }, {
    key: 'AB+', value: 'AB+'
  }, {
    key: 'AB−', value: 'AB−'
  }, {
    key: 'O+', value: 'O+'
  }, {
    key: 'O-', value: 'O-'
  }
  ];
```

In html:

```
<select formControlName="form_control_name">
    <option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.key">{{item.value}} </option>
    </select>
```

To access this value in a method of Ts:

```
 this.formGroupName.value.form_control_name;
```

Input:

In ts:
  you can subscribe to valueChange like,in body of ngOnInit() or constructor()

```
 this.formGroupName.controls['input_text'].valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{

    });
```

Then you can do other manipulation as you needed example:

```
this.formGroupName.controls['input_text'].valueChanges.subscribe(value=>{
   this.getKeyOfValue(value);
    });

getKeyOfValue(value){
foundKey: string = '';
 for(item of items){
   if(item.value == value){
     foundKey = item.key;
     break;
   }
  }

   this.formGroupName.patchValue({
      form_control_name: foundKey
   })

}
```

If you input matches the selected value, it will remain selected. If it does not match,previously selected also will go off. You can control more with little bit of manipulation of above code.